# Usage of MongoDB as a RDFStore for data objects

Tags: mongodb, rdf, sparql, rdfstore

Is there any tool to query MongoDB using SPARQL ?

I store object using an RDF schema (boo Mongo no schema ^^), and now i looking for a tool/server to query the datastore using SPARQL.

I started to write a SPARQL parser, but if such as tool exists, i think i would use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest, if you use RDF, that you have a look at [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org) database, rather than MongoDB. Neo4J is a graph database and is well suited for manipulation of RDF data.

Answer (score 3):

Querying any datastore with SPARQL is rather more complex than just writing a parser - you also need a query engine to process the query and some method to get your data into a form the engine understands OR hook your data into the API of the engine you're using.

I've got both MongoDB and Neo4j down on my lists of Triple Stores to support in my RDF API eventually but this support is months off.  I don't know of any existing SPARQL engines which can query MongoDB